# get data from db and display in table on same page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have two simple interfaces. One accepts sql query the other is popup which display the result. I want to integrate them both. I mean i dont wnat the popup. Instead the result should be displayed on same page. I know it can be done with ajax, but dont know how. I dont want to get into that array stuff(sending data in array form from server). Simply i want the work to be done with the present code with little change..

This is display.jsp

```
<body>
<form action="show.jsp" method="post" target="show.jsp">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="80" name="qry"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Show"/>
```

The below is show.jsp

```
<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/production">
    ${param.qry}
</sql:query>
<body>
    <table width="100%" id="dataTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="col" items="${rs.columnNames}">
                <th>${col}</th>
                    </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rowsByIndex}">
                <tr>
                    <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                        <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
        </c:forEach>
     </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Anyone please give a solution for this(A simple one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is that I add the data I want to display on the web page as an attribute to the request object. After redirecting to the required page, I get the data from the request object and check whether the it is null. If not, I display that data. This way you will be able to dynamically display the data you want to.

Comment: this means the total page is refreshed wright??. I want to update the table at a particular part(suppose a div).

Comment: Yes, I use J2EE. So it works like, Servlet -> Display Page (without the query data) -> Servlet -> Display Page (this time with the query data)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My office hours were over. Actuall i dont want the page to flicker or browse from one to other. Want that to be done staying on same page, any ideas? @Expressions_Galore

Comment: Yes it stays on the same page. Try it and post back if you have any issues.